# Need load more button to move all elements down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a load more button for an Instagram feed on my website but to load more I plan on increasing the height of that section and moving the rest of the page down... I have tried this

```
<script>
$(document.ready(function(){

$('#movedown').click(function(){
    $('.galleryback').animate({
        'minHeight' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.insta').animate({
        'maxHeight' : "+= 50%"
    });

    $('.salonback').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.our').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.salon').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.salonunderlineleft').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.salonunderlineright').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.salonscissors').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.salonmaincopy').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.salontourbutton').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.salonmirrorimage').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.mapback').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.organic33title').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.organic33underline').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.organic33address').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.mapitself').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.mapoverlay').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.contactback').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.howto').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.contactus').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.contactunderlineleft').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.contactscissors').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.contactunderlineright').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.contactformcol1').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.contactformcol2').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.sendbutton').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.footerback').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.footerfbicon').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.footertwttricon').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.footermidtext').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
    $('.footercopyright').animate({
        'top' : "+= 50%"
    });
});
}));

</script>
```

From that I hope you understand what I mean, I want to on button click, Increase the minimum height of one section, the maximum height of another and then move all other elements down by 50%...

What I am asking for is:
a) a more efficient way to achieve this, that JavaScript cannot be the best way to do this
b) To make this work as currently I am getting an error on the start saying the function is undefined.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

a) An easy fix would be to just add a class to all of those elements that is the same. i.e.

```
<div class="salonback commonClass"></div>
<div class="our commonClass"></div>
<div class="salon commonClass"></div>
```

etc...

Then in the javaScript:

```
$('.commonClass').animate({
    'top' : "+= 50%"
});
```

b) You set up the jQuery wrong, do this:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    ....
});
```

not

```
$(window.ready(function() {
    ....
}));
```

Comment: Made your suggested changes, stopped all the errors but now the button still doesn't do anything... Any ideas?